# Skiddle API key not found in GET request

Tags: api, skiddle-api

I'm trying to make a simple request on Skiddle's API, docs [here](https://github.com/Skiddle/web-api/wiki/Authentication).

I made a simple GET request, calling this URL:

https://www.skiddle.com/api/v1/events/search/?api_key=xxxxxxxxxx&latitude=51.509865&longitude=-0.118092&radius=30&keyword=trance&limit=100&offset=0

But I get an error response, "API Key not found".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It works now for some reason. It might be because I was calling http instead of https